# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Storage' not found

Tags: laravel

**what is problem ?**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
use App\User;
use App\Team;
use App\Club;

class TeamController extends Controller
{

  public function destroy($id)
  {
    $team=Team::findOrFail($id);
    $team->delete();
    Storage::delete($team->logo);
    return response()->json(['data' => $team],200);
  }
}
```

Comment: Not using a facade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delete the `$team->logo` before you delete the `$team`. If you delete `$team` first, `$team->logo` doesn't exist any longer.

// import the storage facade

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

public function destroy($id)
{    
    $team=Team::findOrFail($id);
    Storage::delete($team->logo);
    $team->delete();

    return response()->json(['data' => $team], 200);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to declare a use statement for storage

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
use App\User;
use App\Team;
use App\Club;
```

> add this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to access method of **Storage** class and it's under  Class **'App\Http\Controllers'** namespace. That's why its trying to load class from Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Storage' , which is actually not exist. So you should import your **Storage** class at the top using class alias or Full path like below

```
//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Storage;

public function destroy($id)
{    
    $team = Team::findOrFail($id);
    Storage::delete($team->logo);
    $team->delete();

    return response()->json(['data' => $team], 200);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if ($team->logo != null && file_exists(storage_path('app/public/' . **Path** $team->logo ))) {
unlink(storage_path('app/public/' . **Path** $team->logo));
}

**Path** - enter your logo path